# Unable to add a button in a seperate layout to the current view

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-view, android-tablelayout

Please have a look at the following code

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        ></TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**game_buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.ace.ticktacktoe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private TableLayout gameBoard;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createUI();
        //Create the user interface
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void createUI()
    {
        gameBoard = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.gameBoard);

        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_buttons, null);



        //Add the buttons
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

        Button btn = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ((RelativeLayout)btn.getParent()).removeView(btn);
        tableRow.addView(btn);

        gameBoard.addView(tableRow);
    }

}
```

When I run this code, the added button should be displayed. But, my display is totally blank. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: shouldn't you set a LayoutParams to tableRow?

Comment: @lelloman: I tried. Still No good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((RelativeLayout)btn.getParent()).removeView(btn);
tableRow.addView(btn);
```

change to

```
tableRow.addView(layout);
```

or change `game_buttons.xml` to contain ONLY the button without the layout and use the inflater to create buttons without wrapping layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But, how can I add only a button to he XML?

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence remove wrapping `RelativeLayout` - that's all

Answer (score -1):

Try moving you Button to just activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        ></TableLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```